# When we install npm i ffmpeg , its getting like issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, react-native

./node_modules/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg/dist/umd/ffmpeg.js 55:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (55:4)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |   new Error("failed to import ffmpeg-core.js");

I need to convert avi , wmv files to mp4 type format in react

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.